# how does start() method of thread class call run() method of child class when it implements thread class

Tags: java, multithreading

How does the `start()` method of `Thread` class call the `run()` method of a child class which implements the `Thread` class?

I know when we implement `Runnable` we pass the child class object to the `Thread` class constructor which has parameter of `Runnable`. But in the other case we call the `start()` method, and when the JVM doesn't find `start()` in the child class, it goes to `Thread`. Now to call `run()`, or pass it to the JVM, we need child class reference. How does `Thread` implement it?

That's an interesting thing to know.

Concurrency is achieved by the JVM, but to have it call `run()` of the child we need its reference or address.

Comment: Could you add some code showing where you're confused? Calling `Thread.start()` delegates to native code which will eventually call `Thread.run()` on a new OS thread. If you passed a `Runnable` when constructing the `Thread` that method will call `Runnable.run()`. If you subclass `Thread` you should be overriding `Thread.run()`.

Comment: Be careful of your terminology here.  Java really does not have a concept of "child class".  I think you mean subclass in most places here.  Also be careful of the loaded term "reference" which is often misused.

Comment: You need a tutorial on classes and inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

The `start()` method of a `Thread` instance does *not* call the `run()` method.  What it does is, it creates a new operating system thread, and it makes arrangements for the `run()` method to be called *in* that new thread.*

Meanwhile, the `t.start()` potentially can return before the other thread enters `t.run()`.

---

* How it makes those "arrangements" can be completely different from one operating system to another, but generally, it involves making a system call and passing a pointer to a native function that the OS will call.  The native function most likely will use the [Java Invocation API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html), to get into Java library code that eventually will call `t.run()`.

Answer (score 2):

As noted, `Thread.start` invokes a native method, which in turn invokes `Thread.run`:

```
public synchronized void start() {
    startImpl();
}

private native void startImpl();
```

And the code for `Thread.run` has:

```
public void run() {
    if (runnable != null) {
        runnable.run();
    }
}
```

Here, `runnable` is either `null` or is the `Runnable` instance which was provided when the thread was created.  The link to the runnable instance is through the reference which was provided to the thread constructor, and which is held as an instance value of the thread object.

The key behavior is provided by the run method, which must either be implemented directly on the thread, or must be implemented on the runnable object which was provided to the thread constructor.